# Use period for simple nested attributes using GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I would like to know if there is a way to access the child nested attributes using GSON.

Consider this JSON:

```
data: {
  myobject: {
     name: "test",
     status: {
       active: 1
     }
  }
}
```

I don't want to define an extra class for handling the status, preferably I would like to have a mechanism to access directly the nested attribute.

For example:

```
public class MyObject {

    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;

    @SerializedName("status.active")
    private Boolean active;

}
```

Is there a way to do this using GSON or any other Android JSON parser?

Comment: create status innner class with active field.

Comment: I mention explicitly on the description that I want to avoid that...

Comment: I edited your question to better represent your intentions

Comment: Thanks @TimCastelijns

Answer (score 0):

You can use something called [JsonDeserializer](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html) here's an example:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Double.class, new JsonDeserializer<Double>() {
                @Override
                public Double deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
                    JsonObject jobject = (JsonObject) json;

                    return new MyObject (
                            jobject.get("name").getAsString(),
                            jobject.get("status").getAsJsonObject().get("active").getAsBoolean());
                }
            })
            .create();
```

What happened was that you deserialize that class in a custom way, I didn't test this code but it should work, at least that's the right direction.

Also a constructor to your MyObject

```
public class MyObject {

    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;

    @SerializedName("status.active")
    private Boolean active;

    public MyObject(String name, Boolean active){
        this.name = name;
        this.active = active;
    }
}
```

> **TIP:** you could also use [JsonSerializer](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonSerializer.html) to do the opposite, take a class and serialize it in a custom way like removing certain things using conditions

Comment: Even though this answer is going on the right direction, it generates more boilerplate code than using an extra inner class... What I am looking for is a generic extension of the SerializerName annotation to be able to use it in any class and recursively.